# How to implement routing protocols on Estinet network simulator?

Tags: routes, traffic-simulation, vehicle-routing, ad-hoc-network

I am trying to implement routing protocols such as AODV and DSR in a vanet simulation using Estinet ( previously called NCTUns network simulator ) https://www.estinet.com/ns/.

However, i cant find any information on how this is achieved. Is there any information available on how to implement routing protocols on Estinet/NCTuns? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I still have no answer but these papers are available for help for anyone in the future. http://nsl.cs.nctu.edu.tw/NSL/nctuns.html